# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 IsInCompanyRole(role,company)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I want to create a method to find if the user has the '**Role**' for specific '**Company**'.

My '**UserRole**' table contains '***CompanyId***' as foreign key to the company table along with '*UserId*' and '*RoleId*'.

I am struggling to implement a method to use with the notation like '**`User.IsInCompanyRole(role,company)`**',  as the '**`User.IsInRole`**' method.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: IsInCompanyRole should be extension method and you can manage roles for companies with custom claims.
Please research it and try something, once you tried it and you get stuck, come back and we will help you finish it

Comment: Thanks @Zoran. Found the solution with your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution as @Zoran mentioned. No need of claims for me right now. Create the extension method works like a charm.
[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)

Here is my extention.

```
public static class Extention
{
    public static bool IsInCompanyRole(this IPrincipal user, string role, int companyId)
    {
        // Code goes here
    }
}
```

ans usage is simple like

```
User.IsInEntityRole("Admin",1)
```

Comment: glad I could help :)